# Documenting enum values causes MikTex error?

Tags: c, enums, doxygen, miktex

Im attempting to document enum values in C, using doxygen.

My entire project documentation builds fine (including struct member documentation that uses the same format documentation), until I attempt to add documentation for enum values.

When I attempt this, doxygen runs without error, but attempting to make the PDF results in MiKTex failing at makeindex as the general purpose index processor stops unexpectedly. If I let the build continue after this point it appears to get stuck insome kind of infinite loop as the build never ends...

How I am currently attempting to document enum values:

```
/** @file filename.h
 *  @brief some description
 */

// Other documented code that builds fine...

/** A type that allows selection of a bar snsr (This builds fine also). */
typedef enum foo {
    barA = 0,           /**< Bar snsr A (either of these cause the build error). */
    barB = 1,           /**< Bar snsr B (either of these cause the build error). */
    numberOfBars = 2
} foo_t;
```

Screenshot of build with error:
[image: Screenshot of build with error]
Im building on win7 64-bit

This seems to be an issue only since I upgraded doxygen from 1.8.4 to 1.8.8

Has anybody else seen similar? And maybe has a fix? Thanks

Comment: Good question. I don't know. However, have you looked at the doxy changesets between 1.8.4 and 1.8.8? That might help.

Comment: @JayInNyc, just was reading through them there when you commented :) But nothing I can directly relate to this issue :(

Comment: Just reading your question again -- have a look at the makeindex result. See if you can find that bug. In fact -- just do a diff between the makeindex result(s) using doxy 1.8.4 and 1.8.8.

Comment: I had to downgrade to 1.8.4, too.  I wonder if this is related: http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2144/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved in newer versions of doxygen, specifically I am currently using 1.8.9.1 without this issue.